Register external protocols using electron with electron-builder
I am using latest electron "electron": "29.1.6" with "electron-builder": "24.13.3" to build my windows app. I am trying to set my app as default EMAIL app in windows but the problem lies in the fact that my app is not shown there.
I have registered protocol in "electron-builder" using:
  "build": {
    "protocols": {
      "name": "TestApp",
      "schemes": [
        "mailto"
      ]
    }...

Is that enough? Is this possible to test locally, or should I build my app. WHen I build it, the app is showed under "Apps & features". However in "Default apps" under "Set defaults by app" my app is not visible...
I tried adding different protocols withotu success.Should I register protocol like that? OR what is use of protocol?
app.whenReady().then(() => {
  protocol.handle('mailto', () => {
    console.log('App was run with the following arguments: ');
    return new Response('<h1>hello, world</h1>', {
      headers: { 'content-type': 'text/html' },
    });
  });
});

